# Diagnostics for a mixed effects logistic regression model using lmer() in r-project

Tags: r

I am trying to carry out diagnostics on the mixed effects logistic regression model below .

```
mod <- lmer(CEever ~    (1|SL)  
        + birthWeightCat 
        + AFno
        + FRAgeY*factor(genCat)
        + damGirBir
        + factor(YNSUPPLEM), 
        data=Data,  family="binomial")
```

The data for this model is in the form:

```
head(data)

         CalfID CEever birthWeightCat AFno FRAgeY damGirBir YNSUPPLEM
305 CA010110001      1            <20    2     48     140.0         1
306 CA010110002      1          21-25    1     45     144.0         0
307 CA010110004      0          21-25    1     47     151.5         0
308 CA010110005      0            <20    2     71     147.0         0
309 CA010110006      0            <20    1     57     141.5         1
310 CA010110007      0            <20    1     53     141.5         1
```

I can plot the residuals:

```
res <- resid(mod) 
plot(res)
```

.... but can't get values for leverage or Cook's Distance and Dfbeta.

Firstly are these useful techniques for use with this model type, and then if so what code have people used to get these values.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [influence.ME package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/influence.ME/index.html) at CRAN.

Comment: Hi there, I had already attempted to use this package which seems to work for linear but not for logistic mixed effects models. I was using it as below:                                                       alt.est <- estex(modJ, "SL")
    Error in UseMethod("fixef") : 
    no applicable method for 'fixef' applied to an object of class "mer"
    Error in which(substr(names(fixef(model)), 1, 6) != "estex.") : 
    error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'which'

Comment: Having not used this forum I somewhat messed up the above reply! I meant to say thank you so much for your prompt reply and do you know what I'm doing wrong in the above code using estex(). (I have included the error msg gained above.) The formatting above was a disaster so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
alt.est <- influence(modJ, group = "SL")
```

will produce an estex object from which you may derive dfbetas, cooks d, etc.

```
alt.est.cooks <- cooks.distance(alt.est)
alt.est.dfB <- dbetas(alt.est)
```